# Why Can't I do decltype on an Extraction Operator

Tags: c++, c++11, compile-time, decltype, extraction-operator

It seems like this should be legal:

```
decltype(declval<istream>().operator>>(declval<istream>(), declval<int>())) test;
```

But when I try to compile I get:

> error C2661: `std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>`: no overloaded function takes 2 arguments

Am I doing something wrong? Why doesn't this evaluate to an `istream`?

**EDIT:**

It [has been pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697716/why-cant-i-do-decltype-on-an-extraction-operator#comment70591077_41697716) out that because `istream& istream::operator>>(int&)` is a method, the first value is passed automatically.

However: `decltype(declval<istream>().operator>>(declval<int>())) test;` errors with:

> error C2664: `std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits<char>> *)`: cannot convert argument 1 from `std::ios_base::iostate` to `std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &)`

And `decltype(istream::operator >> (declval<istream>(), declval<int>())) test;` errors with:

> error C2661: `std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>`: no overloaded function takes 2 arguments

Comment: A member `oparator<<` of `istream` will not take `istream` as a first parameter.

Comment: @StoryTeller You're saying that will be passed implicitly then right?

Comment: @JonathanMee - as is always the case with member functions.

Comment: Why not simply use `decltype(std::declval<std::ifstream &>() >> std::declval<int>())`? This should work even for non-member overloads of `operator >>`...

Comment: `istream& istream::operator<<(const int&)` is not a thing, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Barry I miss-typed. I think I cleaned it up correctly? Or are you seeing one that I'm missing?

Comment: @JonathanMee About edit: `operator>>` is **not** static. It cannot be called directly on class `istream` (unless you want to take address of it or want to use it in one or two other cases)

Comment: @Barry Oops.  Comment remvoed

Comment: Why not just use `istream&` instead of all the nouveau metatypoclassology?

Comment: @n.m. Yeah, I'm actually trying to use this in an `enable_if` to ensure that the extraction operator exists.

Comment: @Barry Ugh, I've edited again.

Comment: @W.F. Honestly I tried, but failed at the syntax, somehow or other, I'm making all kinds of dumb mistakes today.

Comment: @JonathanMee I know that in production code one shouldn't but for the type debug purpose I find it easier to use `typeid(decltype(STH)).name()` + `c++filt -t RESULT`. This of course don't help you with references but should, but as long you remember this it can be really helpful

Comment: @W.F. It seems like what you're offering here is simply over my head. What is `STH` and is `c++filt -t RESULT` some kind of crazy code syntax I've never heard of?

Comment: @JonathanMee I meant something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a380fbe84d8d2eb8). Of course this can't solve every possible problem but when you're not sure about the type of something it clearly does the trick.

Comment: @W.F. I getcha. I was actually looking to use this in an `enable_if` though. So while this is helpful as a surefire check of function availability, I need the meta-programming support, provided by your and the answer's suggestion.

Comment: @JonathanMee sure you want :) but you could inspect the types in a run-time to apply the knowledge in compile-time :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `operator>>` that takes an `int` is a member function (you're currently using the syntax for both member *and* nonmember functions) and it takes its argument by reference (so that it can populate it - `declval<int>()` gives you an `int&&`, you need `declval<int&>()` to get an `int&`):

```
using T = decltype(declval<istream>().operator>>(declval<int&>()));
```

Even better would be to not invoke the operator directly, so you don't have to worry about which `operator<<` is a member and which is not:

```
using T = decltype(declval<istream&>() >> declval<int&>());
```